# How is this generating a null reference exception?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

The following code is raising a System.NullReferenceException:

```
        if (!App.AppIsSuspending && groupedItemsViewSource != null)
            groupedItemsViewSource.Source = null;
```

specifically in Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.CollectionViewSource.put_Source(Object value).

I'm really struggling to understand how or why this can be happening. What am I misunderstanding about this?

I guess I could wrap it in a try...catch but I really don't understand why it is blowing up.

This is in a WinRT app running on Windows Phone, although I don't have enough telemetry information to tell me if the phone is running Windows Phone 8.1 or Windows 10 Mobile.

**Update:** just to be clearer, the exception is actually happening in CollectionViewSource.put_source. I suspect that there is a bug in the underlying code that is trying to release the previous value but isn't testing that it might be null. Here is the actual exception record:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.CollectionViewSource.put_Source(Object value)
   at Relative_History.ViewEvent.<OnNavigatedFrom>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__3(Object state)
   at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
```

I'm going to write a small demo app to test my theory. I was going to delete the question since I can do more research but people had already started to answer, so felt that was the wrong thing to do.

**Update**: groupedItemsViewSource is declared in the XAML for the page that is raising the exception, thus:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        ItemsPath="GroupMembers"
        IsSourceGrouped="True"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

However, writing a simple one-page app that just does:

```
groupedItemsViewSource.Source = null;
```

in the code-behind doesn't trigger the same behaviour. I've tested this with WP8.1 and W10M emulators.

I'm a little uncertain as to why the async bits are included in the exception log as well. The full OnNavigatedFrom is:

```
    protected override async void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("ViewEvent:OnNavigatedFrom");

        if (!App.AppIsSuspending && groupedItemsViewSource != null)
            groupedItemsViewSource.Source = null;

        if (evm != null)
        {
            evm.GroupBuildingCompleted -= HandleGroupBuildingCompleted;
            await evm.CancelGroupBuilding();

            if (!App.AppIsSuspending)
            {
                evm.NoLongerInUse();
                evm = null;
            }
        }

        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);

        if (!App.AppIsSuspending)
        {
            this.navigationHelper.LoadState -= navigationHelper_LoadState;
            this.navigationHelper.SaveState -= navigationHelper_SaveState;
#if WINDOWS_APP
            this.SizeChanged -= ViewEvent_SizeChanged;
#endif
        }
    }
```

and, as you can see, there isn't any async code leading up to the *groupedItemsViewSource.Source = null* line.

**Update**: I'm still trying to figure out how async is playing a part in the exception stack. Unless I'm misunderstanding things, *at Relative_History.ViewEvent.d__12.MoveNext()* would suggest that the code has returned after an await? But the only await in OnNavigatedFrom is after I'm setting groupedItemsViewSource.Source to null ...

Or am I misinterpreting the exception stack trace?

Comment: Debug to see which variable is null and find the reason.

Comment: Please add the important part of the exception showing the System.NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

are you setting groupedItemsViewSource elsewhere (in a different thread) to null?

Thread 1:

```
if (!App.AppIsSuspending && groupedItemsViewSource != null)
    groupedItemsViewSource.Source = null;
```

Thread 2:

```
groupedItemsViewSource = null;
```

If so:
It might happen that your code of thread 1 did the check, then thread two sets the variable to null and afterwards thread 1 tries to access the source with the seen result.

To prevent this you can use the lock mechanism of .Net.

Define a lock field in your class

e.g.:

```
object lockGroupedItemsViewSource = new object();
```

and use it in all threads where you access the groupedItemsViewSource.

Thread 1:

```
lock(lockGroupedItemsViewSource)
{
    if (!App.AppIsSuspending && groupedItemsViewSource != null)
        groupedItemsViewSource.Source = null;
}
```

Thread 2:

```
lock(lockGroupedItemsViewSource)
{
    groupedItemsViewSource=null;
}
```

Cheers

Thomas

Comment: I've done a code search and I'm not explicitly setting groupedItemsViewSource to anything anywhere. It is only defined in the XAML and I'm struggling to understand how the page could be unloading before OnNavigatedFrom finishes execution.